# How do I divide one column in gnuplot?

Tags: charts, gnuplot

I have gnuplot data file. 
I would like to plot it, but divide every value in the x-axis by n.

Can I do this from within gnuplot, or do I have to rewrite the data file?

Comment: This operation is commonly known as "scaling", maybe that word merits to be in the title?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming that the `x` values are in the first column of the file `'test.dat'` and the `y` values are in the second column of the same file, then you can write:

```
plot 'test.dat' using ($1/n):($2)
```

See [the manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-13400034.1.9) for more information and examples on the `'using'` keyword.

Note that this will not change the values of your data file `'test.dat'`. If you prefer to rewrite the data file, you can do it using `awk`.
For example:

```
awk '{print $1/n,$2}' test.dat > testnew.dat
```

will substitute the `x` values in the first column of `test.dat` with `x/n` and will generate a new file called `testnew.dat`.

Comment: Submitted an edit to fix a broken link to the last HTML version of the manual. Also note that the manuals are only available as PDF in recent versions. http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html

Comment: We can even divide the values of certain columns: `plot "path/to/data.dat" using 1:($5/$3) with lines`